# AppleScript: Reveal POSIX file with variable

Tags: macos, applescript

can someone explain why this does not work?

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
   set myFile to "/Users/"
   reveal POSIX file myFile
end tell
```

This change will work:

```applescript
reveal myFile as POSIX file
```

Strange is, that both versions work without variables:

```applescript
reveal POSIX file "/Users/"
reveal "/Users/" as POSIX file
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Matt Neuburg](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.105.1.134/1/) writes

> Do not confuse a coercion with an object string specifier!    (See
>   "Object String Specifier" in Chapter 11.)
>
> This is a coercion:    "feathers:" as alias
>
> This is an object string specifier:   alias  "feathers:"
>
> The distinction can be crucial. There are circumstances where the
>   coercion will compile but the object specifier will not. You can't
>   compile an alias specifier that uses a literal string unless the file
>   exists, but you can compile a coercion from any string to an alias.
>   And there are circumstances where the object string specifier will
>   compile but the coercion will not. You can form a file specifier using
>   a pathname string, but you can't coerce a string to a file object .
>   (See "File Coercions," later in this chapter.)

Maybe the reason can be found here!

Comment: That is pretty much it. First of all, what happens when there are  string literals involved, is that probably the Applescript compiler, translates this into and intermediary form, and then sees what it has to do to make it work. For the other cases with variables, it sees Posix file var, it is translatates that into aha: I am getting a class cfurl variable now (File://path /to/your/file), but it isn't there,just a regular posix path, and then it fails. When it is **coerced**, then it takes your posix path, and converts that to a cfurl (File://your/file.txt), and passes that over *as* a cfurl.